HangFire Schedule method not firing when used with Enqueue inside BackgroundJib Server
[Latest version of HangFire Nuget Package used]
I have created a service in .NET 6 for taking care of one corn job. I need to execute a method right away and schedule it to execute again after some hours to take care of some business action based on user data.
As instructed in Program.cs I had registered HangFireService to use InMemoryStorage(as our service will be active all time) with HangFireServer as below,
builder.Services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration.UseInMemoryStorage());

// Add the processing server as IHostedService
builder.Services.AddHangfireServer();

And in the service file, I have below code lines in the execute async method
using(var server = new BackgroundJobServer()){
  BackgroundJob.Enqueue(
    () => _logger.LogInformation("Fire-and-forget!"));

BackgroundJob.Schedule(
    () => _logger.LogInformation("Delayed!"),
    TimeSpan.FromHours(7));
}

When the service is running, the first LogInformation executes right away and able to see the message in log file. But the Schedule is not working even though
Jobid is creating and service is still up and running.
On analyzing the logs, found HangFire log saying background job server shutting down immediately after creating schedule job. I tried adding options for setting the shutdown time limit property as 7hours. But no luck.
As per poc, I need to execute a corn method right away and schedule the same corn method later. Am I missing anything here.

Is your server set to "always on"? if not this may be your issue (was for me before)

In HangFireServer service setup at Program.cs or in the BackgroundJobServer instance it has to be set ?

The issue with my code is, I had registered HangFire to use InMemeoryStorage in both Program.cs and Worker.cs files mistakenly. After removing the InMemoryStorage from Worker.cs now schedule is working when used with Enqueue method.

When you add a line:
// Add the processing server as IHostedService
builder.Services.AddHangfireServer();

This will register BackgroundJobServerHostedService as IHostedService. You don't need to create a new instance of BackgroundJobServer to enqueue the job.
The BackgroundJobServerHostedService creates a BackgroundJobServer and has it running with options , storage info etc. To trigger the job you only need to call:
 BackgroundJob.Enqueue(
    () => _logger.LogInformation("Fire-and-forget!"));
BackgroundJob.Schedule(
    () => _logger.LogInformation("Delayed!"),
    TimeSpan.FromHours(7));

Or you can inject IBackgroundJobClient:
public class Foo : IFoo
{
  private IBackgroundJobClient _backgroundJobClient { get; set; }
  private ILogger<Foo> _logger {get;set;}
  public Foo(IBackgroundJobClient backgroundJobClient,
  ILogger<Foo> logger)
{
   _backgroundJobClient = backgroundJobClient;
   _logger = logger;
}
 public Do()
{
  _backgroundJobClient.Enqueue(() => _logger.LogInformation("Fire-and-forget!"));
 _backgroundJobClient.Schedule(
    () => _logger.LogInformation("Delayed!"),
    TimeSpan.FromHours(7));
}
}

